# Wake display, via trigger and then have it sleep after n minutes?

Tags: power-management

We are looking at mixing a [PIR](https://diyhacking.com/raspberry-pi-gpio-control/) (motion sensor) with a Raspberry Pi, such that the screen will turn on when motion in sensed and then sleep after a certain period of no sensed motion. The screen will be connected via HDMI and the OS will be Raspbian Jessie on a Pi 3.

What methods are available to be able to tell the display to wake and then put it stand-by?

For the timeout it appears /etc/kbd/config, with possibly:

```
BLANK_TIME=1
POWERDOWN_TIME=14
```

Is this the right way to go about this, if the desktop environment is Pixel?

For wake, I am not sure? I will be using nodejs, if it makes a difference. Additionally, are there any other methods to have a Pi reduce power consumption on periods of inactivity?

Answer (score 1):

From the command-line, this apparently works:

```
DISPLAY=:0
xset s reset
```

Or there is the tvservice approach (Pi specific):

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice --preferred
```

This activates the preferred display.

References:

- https://github.com/paviro/MMM-PIR-Sensor/blob/master/node_helper.js
- https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/tvservice/tvservice.c